# C# - Nested Loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, nested-loops

I'm doing a simple c# exercise. The problem is I want to show output such as:

*Output*

> Sample 1 => a
>
> Sample 2 => b
>
> Sample 1 => c
>
> Sample 2 => d
>
> Sample 1 => e
>
> Sample 2 => f

Here's input 1 :

```
Sample 1 => 
Sample 2 =>
```

Here's input 2 :

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Here's my code

```
foreach (string input1 in RichTextBox1.Lines)
{
    foreach (string input2 in RichTextBox2.Lines)
    {
        RichTextBox3.Text += input1 + input2 + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

But it doe's not work .can anyone help me. thank you..

Comment: I don't think you need a nested-loops, maybe a int to flip remember the position of `input1` is fine

Comment: _"it doe's not work"_ is a uselessly unspecific problem description, especially given the lack of a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using modulo (%), and use RichTextBox2.Lines as the outer loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<RichTextBox2.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    var length = RichTextBox1.Lines.Length;
    RichTextBox3.Text += RichTextBox1.Lines[(i%length)] + RichTextBox2.Lines[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Looks complicated, but modulo gives you what you want even if there is a Sample 3, Sample 4, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to corresponding elements of two sequences. So you can use LINQ's [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method easily to achieve this result like this (Also by using [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method we didn't use any loop.):

```
richTextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                    Enumerable.Repeat(richTextBox1.Lines, richTextBox2.Lines.Count())
                    .SelectMany(c => c).Zip(richTextBox2.Lines, (f, s) => f + " => " + s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that would give you the expected output:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var input2 in RichTextBox2.Lines)
{
    string input1 = RichTextBox1.Lines[i % RichTextBox1.Lines.Length];
    RichTextBox3.Text += input1 + input2 + Environment.NewLine;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are looping your second input ... for each first input! Again, and again, and again.

So: you only need **one** loop here. Here is some pseudo code to get started:

```
... first check that both line counts are equal
for (int i=0; i<linecount; i++) {
    RichTextBox3.Text += input1[i] + input2[i] + Environment.NewLine
}
```

Where `input1[i]` basically translates to: you have to push the content of your two initial boxes into an array for example.